# How will the gnome2 notification area removal affect apps on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: gnome2, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indicator applet-less applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11349/indicator-applet-less-applications)

If I understood it correctly the plan is to remove the notification area from the gnome2 applet, blocking notifications from all apps except java and wine.
How will this affect other applications (e.g. skype) which depend on the notification area interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those apps will simply not have a notification area icon. The plan for skype is to use their newer proprietary library api which hopefully will integrate into empathy (and other clients) instead of using the proprietary client.

Comment: There are other 3rd party apps which don't have such a solution, eventually there will be some kind of whitelist mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

java and wine apps will have a notification area icon. other apps wont