# How can I use Alltray in Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04

I've been using alltray with teamviewer to make to system tray. With 11.04 unity interface its not working. I know, Unity have deprecated some of the tray features. How can I get teamviewer to move to tray and not to be placed in unity place holder all the time. ?.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [How do I access and enable more icons to be in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-the-system-tray), but swap dropbox for Alltray.

Comment: Thanks, It works. I need to log out and log in after adding to whitelist.

Comment: I couldn't open the application by clicking the tray icon. I had to undock it and dock again. How do I fix it ?

Comment: @sudurais I had the same issue as well.

Comment: Have any of you filed it as a bug in Alltray? https://bugs.launchpad.net/alltray/+filebug

Comment: Nope. Its good to file one..

Comment: any tip for 14.04?