# how to make `alltray` work on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: system-tray

`alltray` has an excellent option that gives us great customizability:
`--menu; -m: "menu text:command": add entry to popdown menu`

just to run test it I am using tho ex.: `alltray xev`

it is installable on ubuntu 16.04.

using `kwin` it will fail with 
`ERROR get class hints`

using with `metacity` (my preferred for speed) or `compiz` gives 
`Alltray: no system tray/notification area found.`

what can be done to let it work? preferably on metacity.

as an alternative answer, any equivalent application or script that has an equivalent option to `--menu` will do it.

[this wont work](https://askubuntu.com/a/35088/46437), outdated.

Comment: I have just posted an answer with an alternative tool, but since you are explicitly asking to let `alltray` work because of the nice `--menu` option, I realized that perhaps the alternative tool I suggested does not help for your particular issue and I deleted the answer for now. What do you think? If you think that even without the `--menu` option an alternative tool may still help, I can undelete the answer.

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 feel free to post it, may help. I just tried alltray again and it is not showing (I think it is waiting to recognize some 'system tray applet' and doesnt for the current ones running), so if yours shows something will be better than what we have now :)

Comment: done! Again, the alternative tool does not have advanced features like the `--menu` option, but it should do what `alltray` is usually supposed to do :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer (TL;DR)

`alltray` is not maintained anymore, if you are using KDE use [kdocker](https://github.com/user-none/KDocker) instead.
(it may also work with Gnome)

It's as easy as:

```
sudo apt-get install kdocker
```

#### Details

As you can see from [their repository](https://github.com/mbt/alltray) and from [this post](https://github.com/mbt/alltray/issues/5) the `alltray` tool is not being maintained anymore.

Because of this, even if you try to compile it from source it would be very difficult to get it working, since it is based on old standards and old/obsolete libraries. For example, it is based on old standards for the [Vala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_(programming_language)) language and if you try to compile it with recent Vala compilers it even generates *syntax errors*.

The `kdocker` tool is [still maintained](https://github.com/user-none/KDocker) instead, and it is very easy to install it on Ubuntu 16.04 as shown above.

It works almost exactly like `alltray`, if you want to cancel "docking" just click with the right mouse button instead of left button (<kbd>Esc</kbd> will not work).

It surely works with KDE, I didn't test it with Gnome (the fact that its name starts with K means nothing, many applications like Kate or Konsole still work with Gnome).

Comment: I should be able to test it also with Gnome and to update this answer in the next few days, if you are able to test it with Gnome earlier please feel free to edit and update the answer.

Comment: my kdocker is version 4.6-2, should I update it? with `kdocker xev` I get "Could not find a matching window for xev in the specified time: 5 seconds.". It allows we select any application to dock it in tray what is interesting, but doesnt work as only the first selected will show up.

Comment: The explanations about alltray abandon is a good answer tho. So in short it is not possible unless we fork and continue from where they stopped, so that alone deserves +1. The kdocker alternative is not working for me, if you have more tips about it would be cool :)

Comment: I use compiz/unity.

Comment: @AquariusPower What do you mean when you say "only the first selected will _show up_?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78737/discussion-between-kubuntuer82-and-aquarius-power).