# What is GSettings and what does Unity use it for?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I've seen solutions for Unity issues involving GSettings, such as

[How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration/29577#29577)

and 
[How do I access and enable more icons to be in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-the-system-tray/30748#30748)

I haven't found out how to use it with Unity.  Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GSettings is an API that allows you to access key/value pairs (e.g., persistent application settings) without directly talking to the actual backend that stores that data (config files, gconf, dconf).