# What file saves my launcher bar items?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

Where can I find the file that saves the state of my launcher items?

[image: screenshot of launcher icons]

I have a couple desktops, and I'd like to synchronize the state of my launcher items between them, like dotfiles. I'll take care of the scripting logistics for installation merge conflicts. My specific question is how is this state currently saved, and where on the machine might I find the file(s) that stores that information? I'm assuming this is some XML/JSON/CSV/etc set that points to an executable path, icon path, and numeric position on bar.

Comment: It's not XML, JSON, CSV or some easily parseable file. It's a binary database like the Windows registry called [Gsettings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35172/what-is-gsettings-and-what-does-unity-use-it-for). You will have to use the gsettings command or APIs.

Comment: @muru oh thanks for the reading material; how naïve I am...