# How to show icon Googsystray?

Tags: 11.04, panel, unity-2d, notification-area

I have upgrade my ubuntu from maverick to natty, and my problem is Googlesystray not show in panel. but the app is work. how to show icon notification in unity panel?

Comment: Not until someone creates an Application indicator for it for the top panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to **whitelist** Google Systray in the panel by [running dconf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-the-system-tray/30748#30748) or by [running gsettings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35289/one-line-command-for-adding-new-items-to-com-canonical-unity-panel-systray-whitel).

Answer (score 6):

If you know the command for it, install [dconf-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools], then open `dconf-editor` (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> `dconf-editor`) add an exception to the whitelist. You can also replace the whitelist with "all" to allow all applications.

[image]

You need to run <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> `unity --replace` afterwords.

Comment: hi Roland, thanks for tutorial. I have success for it

Comment: @fanoy if it worked for you, click the arrow on my answer to mark the question solved.