# Application Indicator for Shutter

Tags: unity, indicator, shutter

Looking through the [list of application indicators](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators?s=1ccf7c8a-221e-4d01-bfa9-4939370ecfd3), I see [screenshots](http://cdn.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Selection_00111.png) that appear to have a Shutter indicator. Where can I find & install this?

Comment: This issue is addressed in a [post on the Shutter blog](http://shutter-project.org/2011/03/0-87-2-adds-quicklist-support/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Until they get perl bindings for app indicator, you can whitelist Shutter systray as per the one-line command posted in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35289/one-line-command-for-adding-new-items-to-com-canonical-unity-panel-systray-whitel),

> gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "$(gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist | sed -e "s/]$/, 'shutter']/")"

---

GUI Editor method

1. Install [`dconf-tools`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools)[image: Install dconf-tools]
2. Open **dconf-editor**

   ***Run Command*** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `dconf-editor`
3. **Navigate** to `desktop => unity => panel`

   [image]
4. Add the text `,'shutter'` to the end of the list (inside the square bracket).
5. Close dconf-editor and restart Unity (***Run Command*** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `unity`)

Comment: It would be the application executable name, test in Terminal. So dropbox and pidgin would be as is. You could alternatively replace the list with just `['all']`

Comment: I ultimately just put in ['all']. Now I get my blinking pidgin systray back :) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Is it necessary to restart Unity after this change?

Answer (score 8):

Shutter doesn't have an indicator because there are no indicator bindings for Perl.

Instead I keep shutter on my launcher and just use the quicklists to do take fast screenshots:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Andrei from WebUpd8 has written an application indicator for Shutter. It isn't *perfect*, but you should find it satisfactory. It works in 11.04 and 11.10.

To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-shutter
```

Or:

- Add `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` to your software sources.
- Refresh the sources.
- Install [indicator-shutter[image: Install indicator-shutter]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/indicator-shutter) <--- by clicking on this icon or running

  ```
  sudo apt-get install indicator-shutter
  ```

Instructions taken from [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/ubuntu-application-indicator-for.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is - at least - an official solution with Shutter 0.89, available in Shutter PPA.

To get the official Shutter indicator, you will need to add and upgrade/install from the official stable Shutter PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install shutter
```

Check this article for details: [Shutter Screenshot App Finally Adds an App Indicator](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/shutter-screenshot-app-finally-adds-an-app-indicator)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is the best solution, because it will be the official indicator for Shutter, so will be mantained in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the following additional packages before shutter would appear in the launcher. Even then, it disappears without warning, so you must lock it to the launcher as soon as the app is up:

```
sudo apt-get install libnet-dropbox-api-perl    # Dropbox support
sudo apt-get install libnet-dbus-glib-perl      # UbuntuOne required?
```