# Klipper icon on top panel isn't functioning

Tags: 11.04, unity

When clicking on the klipper icon on the unity bar nothing happens. No drop down list. Is there anybody able to resolve it?..

Comment: Does Klipper, by default, place itself on the Unity dock or the top panel?

Comment: [Potential Duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39843/application-indicator-for-shutter)

Comment: The situation seems to be the same, but if people who have the same problem see stuff about Shutter at the top of a search result, then they don't think the problems are ultimately the same. I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with Klipper not being white listed.

You could try these sets of commands:

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`

and then you run

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'klipper']"`

some additional reading resources can be found here(where i found it at least):

http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/enable-system-tray-notification-for-all-applications-in-ubuntu-11-04/

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1772418.html

Comment: Thanks . But it is not working . Still the same issue.