# How can I hide a running program icon from the notification bar and Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, autohide

[image: Screen Recorder.............]
What can I do for hiding a program icon from the notification bar and Unity Launcher?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove icons from system tray](http://askubuntu.com/questions/508767/remove-icons-from-system-tray)

Comment: depending on the application, sometimes you can run as a daemon

Comment: which one do you want to hide?

Comment: this may help http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GQa8pO4kS0YJ:gotoanswer.stanford.edu/unity_tray_icons-6132665/&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1 specifically, it talks about using dconf tools to whitelist or blacklist applications from the notification area

Comment: The Unity Launcher: impossible, apart from unmapping, but then the window disappears as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide icon of running program from Launcher using CompizConfig Settings Manager.
To install it run:
 `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
To launch run:
 `ccsm`
Then go to section Windows Management, enable Windows Rules. Then choose it, and add this line into "Skip Taskbar":
`title=nameofwindow`
Replace nameofwindow with the title of the window you want to hide.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 there is no option "Windows Rules". Every manual or instruction about ccsm I find on the internet just states 'check Windows Rules' as if it's as natural as water. What has changed and how do I work around it? (side note, all search results about "[Windows Rules](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&biw=1855&bih=982&tbs=qdr%3Ay&ei=bHSbW-GkLsnMwALu2JywDw&q=compiz+config+%22Windows+Management%22+no+%22Windows+Rules%22&oq=compiz+config+%22Windows+Management%22+no+%22Windows+Rules%22)" I find are at least a year old, verified with my Google-Fu)

Comment: same for me, @MarkJeronimus have you found a solution already?

Answer (score -1):

To remove an entry from the launcher, right-click on the icon and select "Unlock from Launcher". To remove items from notification bar, see handy tips from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508767/remove-icons-from-system-tray).