# Make Gnote load faster

Tags: unity, gnote

Ever since I upgraded to 11.04 and started to use Unity I've been bothered by the time it takes to load Gnote. In 10.10 I used Gnome and the Gnote plugin for the Gnome panel which had Gnote loaded in the background so that e.g. opening a new note in Gnote took no time at all.

What I'm looking for in Unity is a way to make Gnote load faster or a way to make Gnote behave as if it loaded faster. I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Preload Gnote so that it starts faster whenever I decide to start it.
2. Automatically start Gnote minimized every time Unity starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the second option is the best bet since there's AFAIK no way to preload Gnote

Just add `gnote` to your `gnome-session-properties` (Startup Applications in Settings) or do this:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/gnote.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
chmod u+x ~/.config/autostart/gnote.desktop
```

Edit: To use Gnote system tray icon, you have to whitelist it first. Use the following command (based on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35289/one-line-command-for-adding-new-items-to-com-canonical-unity-panel-systray-whitel)):

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "$(gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist | sed -e "s/]$/, 'gnote']/")"
```

You can find more information on systray-whitelist in [this post](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html).

Changes will take effect after reloading Unity (logging out or executing `unity --replace`).

Comment: Does this start Gnote minimized?

Comment: Yes, it starts only Gnote status icon.

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions and neither starts Gnote minimized in Unity.

Comment: I see. Have you whitelisted it in system tray?

Comment: What is the system tray and what is whitelisting in Unity? Maybe you are not speaking of Unity since I cannot find "system tray" in [the Unity terminology](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements/19166#19166)

Comment: I have edited the answer with more information. I was assuming that you have enabled the tray icon. Now Gnote will keep running once you enable it in systray.

Comment: Thanks! I used the following to get Gnote to sit in the top panel when I login: `cd .config/autostart/`, `cp gnote.desktop gnote.desktop.old`, `cp /usr/share/applications/gnote.desktop ./`, `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "$(gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist | sed -e "s/]$/, 'gnote']/")`.

Comment: Also you have to turn on the status icon in the Gnote application itself for this to work. To do this you open Gnote and go to Edit > Preferences, then check the 'Use Status Icon' check box.