# How do I start Gnote minimized?

Tags: gnote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tell a start up program to start minimized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20989/how-do-i-tell-a-start-up-program-to-start-minimized)

I am using Unity and I want Gnote to start minimized. When I start it now its search dialog is shown.

If it matters I am not using the standard setup because I have set Gnote to autostart and I have put Gnote in the panel by doing the following (which I learned [from another question](https://askubuntu.com/q/48677/19490)):

```
cd .config/autostart/
cp gnote.desktop gnote.desktop.old
cp /usr/share/applications/gnote.desktop ./
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "$(gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist | sed -e "s/]$/, 'gnote']/")
```

Two screenshots to illustrate.

What I want:
[image: Gnote starts minimized]

What I get now:
[image: Gnote starts with search dialog open]

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE:
I did some looking around and it looks like why it wont minimize to the tray is because it starts before the tray does, so there is no tray for it to minimize to.
So I made a script that delays the start of Gnote so the tray has time to start first.
sleep 5 && gnote -systray
Just put that line is a script file and tell autostart to run that file.
"5" is 5 seconds, so you can change it depending on what you need.

Original Post:
This is how I got Gnote to start minimized on Fedora.
I put a Gnote entry in the autostart and then added `--start-minimized` so it looked like this:

```
gnote --start-minimized
```

but it didn't work.  I was confused because it worked when I put that command in the terminal and it worked, but not when I put it in autostart.
So I found two other commands to try `-min` and `-systray`.
`-min` did the same thing as `--start-minimized` (worked in the terminal but not in autostart)
but then I tryed `-systray` and it worked!
so I put this in autostart and it worked:

```
gnote -systray
```

The reason I posted the other two commands is because I am not sure which one works in Unity or Ubuntu.

By the way, I got the minimize commands from here: [How do I tell a start up program to start minimized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20989/how-do-i-tell-a-start-up-program-to-start-minimized)

Comment: Neither command works nor can I find documentation for them. Do they really exist?

Comment: I'm using Unity (11.10). Even if I try the commands manually (when everything should be started) they won't work.

Comment: Well I have been trying this stuff on Fedora.  I will go try to get it working on Ubuntu.  Are you sure your using Gnote and not Tomboy?

Comment: I'm sure. I'm using Gnote 0.7.5.

Comment: For me `gnote -systray` worked - after enabling 'Use Status Icon' in Gnote-Preferences -> General