# How do I get Liferea 1.8 RC to use the global application menu?

Tags: appmenu, liferea

I just updated Liferea from 1.6 to 1.8 RC thru PPA.

After the update Liferea disappeared from Unitys Global Message indicator in the top menu.

Also there is no standalone icon in Unity. In Gnome classic Liferea 1.8 RC shows an icon in the top Menu. I have the status "icon in notifier" option activated in the settings.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get Liferea to show up again in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly as for the menu issue, Liferea sometimes does not show a menu in the global menu. I'm not sure why, but restarting it usually fixes the problem for me.

As for the icon, you can't get one in Unity unless you whitelist liferea in the systray.

See:

- [One line command for adding new items to com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35289/one-line-command-for-adding-new-items-to-com-canonical-unity-panel-systray-white)
- [How do I access and enable more icons to be in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray)

If you know how to contact the liferea developers, please let them know you would like them to support Ubuntu (and appindicators).

---

*Every voice matters in cases like this, where the developers have chosen not to do something because "we don't use Ubuntu so we don't care". Adding an application indicator for Liferea should be pretty easy, and wouldn't introduce any problems, but they won't do it unless they feel they have a reason.*

Comment: Yes, we really need a new feed reader in Ubuntu. Liferea has a good design, but it is fundamentally flawed in its implementation. If they also don't want it to integrate properly with Ubuntu, that just underscores this need.

Comment: I downloaded dconf and whitelisted liferea in desktop/unity/panel. Now I get an Liferea icon in Unity.