# Array manipulation in gsettings' set command

Tags: gnome, gsettings

Is there an easy way to do array manipulation in `gsettings`? I am comparing gsettings to OS X's `defaults` command  that offers the `defaults domain --array key overwrite-value` and `defaults domain --array-add key added-value` interface for manipulating arrays.

As far as I can tell there is only `gsettings set domain key "['overwrite-value']"` available to gsettings. Not really pretty for when you want to add or remove one entry from an array.

I have seen [a suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/35344/18339) that allow me to add to an array, but I would rather use a interface if there is one.

Answer (score 4):

No, `gsettings` doesn't support any array operations except getting and setting the whole array.

Comment: Would be great to append elements to array (like when [adding custom shorcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal/597414#comment1776277_826328). It's not clear for me where the feature request should be filed, [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues?label_name%5B%5D=GtkSettings)?