# With Unity, Evolution calendar alarms are not persistent. How can I make them so?

Tags: 11.04, unity, evolution, ayatana, calendar

I use alarms attached to events in my Evolution calendar. With Unity, I get the usual notification at the appropriate time, but unlike in 10.10 or previous versions, there is no persistent reminder of the event (no 'alarm clock' icon in the system tray). What can I do to get a persistent reminder of the event? Something needs to turn blue in that panel!  (In my opinion, that should be the date and time.) If someone could suggest any easy way of setting a persistent visual reminder, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: the workaround is to whitelist evolution-alarm-notify using the method described here:
[How do I access and enable more icons to be in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray)

I filed a bug on launchpad, here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/773896
(please use the 'this bug also affects me' option on the page if you want to attract attention to this bug)

Comment: Does the whitelisted evolution-alarm-notify display using OSD-notify? If so, how do you get the notifications to persist onscreen?