# How can I see a list of all the systray icons that are not whitelisted?

Tags: unity, troubleshooting, notification-area

I've learned that Unity does not support systray icons, and that it is possible to grant exceptions for ([whitelist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-the-system-tray)) certain applications. As far as I can tell, there is no general error message displayed when an application is denied an attempt to display unsupported systray icon.

How can I find out what applications are being denied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By observation, in Ubuntu 11.04, whenever an application tries to add an icon to the tray, there is a log entry with the word "TrayChild" in the file .xsession-errors in the user's home directory. You can get the list of denied entries with grep:

```
grep TrayChild "${HOME}/.xsession-errors"
```

To add that application's icon to the tray, which was my question too, the advise in this link works.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1737589

Just execute this command, replace "YOUR_APPLICATION" with the executable name of the application you want to "whitelist".

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'YOUR_APPLICATION']"
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer my question. I want a list of all running "YOUR_APPLICATION"s that I have not yet appended to `systray-whitelist`.

Comment: It seems that whenever an application tries to add an icon to the tray, there is a log entry with the word "TrayChild" in the file .xsession-errors in the user's home directory. You can get the list of denied entries with grep: grep TrayChild .xsession-errors

Comment: That's perfect. If you edit your answer to include this I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: The answer had been edited.