# How to know the name of the systray applications in order to add it one by one on the systray-whitelist?

Tags: indicator

Using the `systray-whitelist ['all']` I got two battery indicators!!! how to know the name of the systray applications in order to add it one by one on the systray-whitelist ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I see a list of all the systray icons that are not whitelisted?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36898/how-can-i-see-a-list-of-all-the-systray-icons-that-are-not-whitelisted)

Answer (score 3):

Found that on a blog

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply \
--dest=com.canonical.indicator.application \
/com/canonical/indicator/application/service \
com.canonical.indicator.application.service.GetApplications | grep "object path"
```

Gives you the names of all running indicators.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Unity2D. Which is unfortunately a giant problem because you can't us the 'all' setting in the systray-whitelist.

Comment: Actually it's the same even in normal Unity...this doesn't seem to list the applications attempting to run in the tray at all.

Comment: some of the indicators' names you can guess from their application/autostart name and try them out in the gconf-editor.

Comment: The biggest problem is guessing as to the capitalization of the application name. It really would be nice to just know what name to look for, either from the application developer/source or some command to search the indicators being hidden.
What special localized string is Unity reading to determine whether an app is allowed in the systray or not?

Comment: If I knew that I would be very happy, as I would like to have 'wicd' in the systray rather than in the indicator applet. But sadly my knowledge in these things is quite limited.