# How can I make the Quark music player work in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity

When I start (strange-)Quark in Natty nothing happens, it doesn't appear in the upper panel next to the network, so I can't use it. How can I fix it?

http://hsgg.github.com/quark/

The worst solution is to just use a normal desktop but that is kind of failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you use **strange-quark** frontend for GNOME notification area. This will now have to be [whitelisted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-the-system-tray) to be able to use it.

Comment: It worked when I added "strange-quark" in dconf-editor aweswome! Thanks!