# How do I show blueproximity's icon in the panel?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, panel, bluetooth

I just upgraded to Natty and am getting used to the new interface.  I depend on blue proximity for locking my desktop when I leave my office.  After upgrade I no longer see the icon in the panel area.  I tested and It is working but I have no idea how to configure it now.  How do I get the icon back and configure it?

Comment: (To whoever tries to answer this, this looks like a whitelist question)

Comment: @Jorge What is a whitelist question?

Comment: See here (basically the same thing binarylife says): http://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the program doesn't show up in the notification area. 
Ubuntu natty has a whitelist for only some programs to show up.
But there's an easy way to either re-enable the Systray for all applications or to whitelist a few applications you can't live without.

To enable the Notification Area (Systray) for all applications, run the following command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

You can only whitelist a certain application if you want, by using the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'YOUR_APPLICATION']"
```

The above command includes the already whitelisted (by default) applications so you should replace "YOUR_APPLICATION" with the application you want to whitelist.

For blueproximity:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'proximity']"
```

In Ubuntu 13.04 the systray-whitelist hard-coded so the above configuration change no longer works. Use this https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/974480/comments/42 ppa and follow the instructions to enable the whitelist and set it to "['all']"

Comment: 'all' was the only thing that worked.

Comment: Whitelisting "blueproximity" doesn't work and I don't want to whitelist all applications. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Alin Andrei: Yes There was an error in the code; `'blueproximity'` should be replaced with `'proximity'` . Thanks for reminding me to fix this:).

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer will not work for version 13.04 and newer, because that whitelist was removed from Ubuntu.

However there is a [patch for blueproximity](http://sourceforge.net/p/blueproximity/patches/4/) to make it work with unity's app indicator.

You can apply the patch as follows:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/p/blueproximity/patches/_discuss/thread/3d5eb592/7e50/attachment/proximity.patch
sudo patch /usr/share/blueproximity/proximity.py < proximity.patch
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

That works in 13.10 and 14.04. Haven't tested other versions. I see no reason why wouldn't work in other versions though. I would also recommend this over the whitelist solution.

Hopefully that patch will be integrated into newer version of blue proximity.