# How to make the android notifer desktop indicator appear on the Unity panel?

Tags: indicator, android, notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access and enable more icons to be in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray/30748#30748)

I was using the [**android-notifier-desktop**](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/) indicator on my Lucid 32bit installation comfortably, but when I changed to Natty amd64, the same setup does not seem to work.

Summary of things:

1. `android-notifier-desktop_0.5.1-0-amd64.deb` is installed.
2. I can see a `java` android-notifier-desktop.jar running in my `ps` list.
3. there is no unity-panel indicator for the notifier (**this is the problem**).
4. I had also added the gnome-panel at the bottom of my desktop;
   Trying to "add to panel..." here also does not show the notifier as an option.

Has anyone setup this notifier on Natty amd64?
Am I missing something here?
Are there any other ways to get the notifier showing?

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/issues/detail?id=383) and as such is now closed. To follow developments, workarounds, and solutions for this bug please use their bug tracker system.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, there is [Issue 383](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/issues/detail?id=383) already filed for this.
But, it does not yet solve the problem `:-)`
If you are interested in getting this to work, login to `code.google.com`and click on the [image] icon.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.04 has disabled the traditional notification area, applications are expected to use indicators.

But the old system is still there and can be activated by hand. You can whitelist an application to let it use the notification area by changing a gconf key. You can get your current values with this command:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist

['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'Dropbox']
```

The second line shows the results in my computer, it's not part of the command.

You can add your app with the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'Dropbox', 'YOUR_APP']"
```

Or just use ['all'] to enable any program to use it:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

Comment: this sounds promising, I'll look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just log in once to the 'Ubuntu (Classic)' desktop, and configure it. Then, it will run like normal with Unity. You won't see the icon, but the notifications will appear as before. You can switch between Unity and Classic any time you need to change it's configuration. The icon is pretty much unnecessary once you set it up. I did this and it works perfectly.

Comment: I recall it was useful on my Lucid installation. Would like to get it working very much.