# Auto-start and play mp3s from usb stick

Tags: autostart

Is there a way that I could auto start a music player and play mp3s from a usb stick immediately after my computer has booted up?  Ideally the music player would play each mp3 file on the usb stick in turn.

Comment: Have you found an answer that works for you?

Answer (score 2):

You could also make a playlist and make an application play that in your startup applications.

For example, if I wanted to play playlist.m3u on startup using vlc media player, I could add this to my startup application like this.

```
Name: ZZ_PlayMusicOnStartup #(This can be named anything to your choice)*
Command: vlc /home/nits/playlist.m3u
```

And click Add

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- [Strange quark](http://hsgg.github.com/quark/)

  Can play music direct from start of the program. Then you need to add the program into `startup applications`

to install quark you need to compile the file, the easiest is to use the command `cd` to get to the folder that the files are in. Then you need to type: `./configure` and then `make install` this will now install quark.

if you are using unity you might have the problem that strange-quark wont show up in the system tray (that is where you control it). That is because it's not in the whitelist. to add it simply follow [this tutoria](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray/30748#30748)l.

- Startup applications

  Go to System --> preferences --> startup
  applications. And then add strange-quark.  The command for starting
  strange-quark is **strange-quark**.

Now we just need to tell strange-quark what music you want to listen to and enabling the auto play.

- Setting up strange-quark

  start strange-quark. 
  click on the load songs button.
  and choose the folder.
  then right click the icon again and select "play on startup".

Now you are off, reboot and see if it works as it should.