# How can I access the systray whitelist?

Tags: indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access and enable more icons to be in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray)

I already tried:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
```

and it didn't work.