# Dconf editor can't make changes to Unity panel/launcher

Tags: unity, editor, dconf

I've been trying to add stuff to the panel and to change the order of the icons in the launcher but there's no effect. It's like the changes aren't saved. I change something, close dconf editor, lock out and back in again and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3D version of Unity is implemented as a plugin for Compiz, so uses Compiz's preferences store (separate from the preferences stored for the 2D version of Unity).

Those preferences are still stored in GConf (which can be edited using the `gconf-editor` program).  The settings you are probably interested in are found under `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options`.

Alternatively, you can use the `compizconfig-settings-manager` to get a slightly more structured view of the plugin settings.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you. I still can't find an option to add icons like compiz fusion icon to the top panel. It'be great if you could tell me how to do that using gconf editor.

Comment: The recommended way to add an icon to the top panel is to write an application using the indicator API (if the application is running, then the indicator is shown).  If you are talking an about an application that used the old system tray API, then the following question might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30742