# alltray only works once in Gnome 3 Shell

Tags: gnome, wunderlist, minimize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access and enable more icons to be in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray)

When I log in I want Wunderlist open minimized at system tray. It works but only once. When I click wunderlist or any other program that was minimized at tray with allray, the program window opens, like should happen, but when I do it again doesn't work and the program window disappears.

I will like solve this problem, if its possible before try other alternatives.

I have ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Have you tried this answer yet: http://askubuntu.com/a/30748/236