# How to open a file in Sublime Text 2 directly from a link in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I use two dev boxes - one is MacBookPro where I use iTerm and one is Ubunu where I use the built-in terminal. In iTerm I have the following neat feature. Say you have run some tests, which fail and you get a backtrace in exactly which file, on which line something went wrong. When I hold Command and click on the file path, the file opens automatically in Sublime Text 2 and the cursor is even on the right line. Can I do something similar in the Terminal on Ubuntu?

Comment: This seems to be the functionality of iTerm and it is not available directly on gnome-terminal! Also have a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/118138/iterm-2-equivalent

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was wondering if there is some Ubuntu alternative. I know there are a terminals like guake, but I need a solution with this specific feature.