# How to use notification area (system tray) over indicators in Xubuntu?

Tags: indicator, xubuntu, system-tray

Xubuntu has both notification area (system tray) and indicators. I prefer the first one, as it allows me to hide items. Is there any way to force the apps that support both (e.g. Tomboy, Dropbox etc) to display their icons in the system tray and not their indicators?

Comment: There's an answer that might be relevant here: - https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray . It uses the terminal to whitelist applications for the systray.

Comment: i've had success with `xfce4-panel -r` (or `xfce4-panel &`, if it's borked). restarting the panel seems to poplate the apps. But i do find app indicators the most annoying problem since release upgrade to 22.04.  I've also `sudo apt install libayatana-appindicator1`, but i'm not 100% sure on this.

Answer (score -1):

This is rather simple. Just remove the indicator plugin from your panel and all bidirectional indicators become notification icons.

Your only loss is:

- the menu-like behavior
- some incompatible, indicator-only items
- some rare icon size changes

Comment: But that's not the point here, I need to retain the indicator plugin for those apps that support only indicators. What I want is to force those that support both to use the tray not their indicators. Some apps have this in their options, some (e.g. dropbox) don't. But still they choose to display the indicator and not the tray icon based on something, hence this should be modifiable. :)