# Gnome Mail Icon not showing up on system tray

Tags: gnome, 12.10, system-tray

I recently wiped my drive and re-installed 12.04 then upgraded back to 12.10. My mail icon that is supposed to be there is not. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several solutions from this topic might help you solve your problem: [How do I access and enable more icons to be in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray)