# Change Unity's indicator messages envelope color from blue

Tags: indicator, email, gsettings

How can I change the "You've got mail" messaging indicator envelope color? Is there a setting similar to as in [allowing any indicators](https://askubuntu.com/a/35620/15058)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indicator is not coded to be a specific colour, instead it switches from the `indicator-messages` stock icon to the `indicator-messages-new` stock icon.

In the `ubuntu-mono-light` and `ubuntu-mono-dark` themes, the -new version happens to be blue.  Other icon themes use different colors.

If you want, you can modify the icon svg from the Ambiance theme:

`gksudo gedit /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/16/indicator-messages-new.svg`

Search for `#19b6ee` (the blue color used by default) and change it to the color of your choice.

Comment: Great! Editing the /22/ sized (?) .svg and clicking on the indicator icon immediately took effect. `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/indicator-messages-new.svg` (dark envelope e.g. #86837E)