# Is there a way to use Xfce integration features with unity?

Tags: unity, xfce, compatibility

Is there a way to use systray icons, pager icons, etc of Xfce apps in the Unity desktop? Orage is an awesome calendar app, but I want to use Unity with it, as that's my preferred DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Unity has a cumbersome way of displaying app activity in the notification area, whereas by default it doesn't include all apps. See [How do I access and enable more icons to be in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray).