# No radiotray app indicator

Tags: lubuntu

I've been using this app for years.
I reinstalled lubuntu 14.04 on a machine then:

```
apt-get install radiotray
```

Executed it from the applications menu. I see it running in task manager but there is no app indicator or controller in the system tray.

Comment: possible duplicated of http://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray

Comment: @Geo those solutions are outdated for 14.04

Comment: well dconf works well here. the only problem is finding the things there because they have changed place. but nothing of a little investigating cant help

Comment: @Geo all answers there are referring to `systray-whitelist`, no such thing in 14.04 any more.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that this may be related to a "well-known" starting applications problem in Lubuntu in some way. Can you see the internet icon or is it missing too?

If that happens too, you can open "Default applications for LXSession" in preferences menu, move to autostart tab, change the "Disable autostarted applications?" setting to "no", check that radiotray is among the enabled known applications, close the windows and log in Lubuntu again to see if it works.

Many people said that this problem may prevent Lubuntu 14.04 from getting updated automatically, so check that Lubuntu is updated before anything if you cannot see the internet icon. An update is supposed to have been released in connection with this problem.

Bye