# No Skype tray icon in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, icons, indicator, skype, system-tray

After installing Ubuntu 15.04 and skype (4.3.0.37) I cannot get Skype indicator to appear in tray

I've tried doing this:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/fix-for-skypepidgin-icon-missing-from-ubuntu-15-04kubuntu-15-04.html

But the icon just doesn't appear after installing those (even after rebooting the system).

I've also tried installing dconf-editor to whitelist all the icons in Unity just like shown here: [How do I access and enable more icons to be in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray) But I don't have such option as "panel" under the "Unity" dropdown!

How can I make the indicator show up in the tray bar? I had it working in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Is Skype autostarted?

Comment: Are you asking if it's autostarted when booting the system? No, I choose it from Dashboard

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 39):

Here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276023 posted the solution worked for me finally on 15.04.

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Then need to restart Skype.

Comment: Does not work for me, using Ubuntu 14.04 32 bits.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either

Comment: This used to work for me on 14.04, but it stopped working when I upgraded. Tbh, I'm surprised Skype even functions properly, considering it's programmed for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I just migrated to Google Hangouts and TeamSpeak.

Comment: Tested many things and options and finally this one worked for me (fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)! Yay!

Comment: It works also on 16.04.

Comment: Working in ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I think this answer must be accepted. So short and nice answer. Punching to eye of the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Running the following command solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: I have `libappindicator1` installed. Skype running. No Skype icon in system tray.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either

Answer (score 1):

this happens to me, only when skype is in autostart (i use lubuntu 12.04)

`sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`
i added skype:

```
@skype %u
```

this works for some months, and when skype history become big, it stop working (skype is loaded, but without tray icon)
first time i fixed it with deleting /home/$user/.skype
but after history was growing same happens. i run skype again and give him exit, and on second run skype have tray icon. i deside to make delay for skype:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

(this is path for Lubuntu, for Ubuntu it's different)

> @/home/myuser/.skype.sh

and create in /home/myuser/ batch file .skype.sh (i want the file to be hidden):

```
sleep 10 && skype %u &
```

i saved file and make executable:

```
chmod +x .skype.sh
```

then reboot...

sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

Install dconf tools:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Open from the terminal:

```
dconf-editor
```

Go to: com -> canonical -> indicator -> messages

In "messages", go to the label "applications" and in values, enter 'skype', including the single quotes, like so:

```
['skype']
```

Then restart the computer and open Skype.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading 4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb and installing on 14.04 I had the same problem.
I tried all the suggestions, but none worked.

Finally I removed the deb installation and used [Software Center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/skype) to install it (4.3.0.37). And the indicator works perfectly.