# Forbid specific application from minimizing to org.freedesktop.ibus.panel

Tags: 22.04, launcher, ibus, dconf, zoom-meeting

The general case:

I want to be able to forbid specific applications from minimizing to the system tray (ibus.panel, upper-right hand of the screen by default) when I attempt to close them - I want them to have to actually exit without having to right click -> quit.

The specific case:

Using the desktop version of Zoom, when I click the "X" in the upper right hand corner, I want the application to stop running.

What I know so far:

- I can use dconf-editor to modify the configuration for org.freedesktop.ibus.panel. I haven't found a list of possible configuration items other than the default ones listed. [In Ubuntu 13.04, there was an allow list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray) and I hope there is still a similar setting, possibly a deny list.
- I can force Zoom to only be launched as a specific user (or at least make this tolerably easy). I don't know what permission I would need to remove from this user to prevent it from having permission to use the Panel.
- I could set up an aggressive cron job (1/min) that pkills Zoom if it can detect Zoom is running and isn't present in the Launcher Bar. I don't know how to programmatically read the list of items in the launcher. I don't like this option but would be satisfied with it.

For each of the above there's really just one piece of information I need and I'd be able to make this work. It is, of course, possible an entirely different solution is far better.

I am completely fine with options that make Zoom complain about crashing when it starts up. They deliberately chose to design their app this way.